# Linux Multiboot with custom grub.conf, unable to boot to OS created on partitions

Tags: grub2, pxe, multiboot

I have a disk partition as below for multiboot, with custom grub and used GRUB  version 0.97(rhel6.10)   for grub embeded to  boot for  correct OS. when i install OS at grub menu i am observing file not found error, Can some one help. but OS has been correctly install on that partition using PXE.

GRUB:

```
device (hd0) /dev/sda
root (hd0,0)
setup (hd0)

Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.


    GNU GRUB  version 0.97  (640K lower / 3072K upper memory)

 [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.  For the first word, TAB
   lists possible command completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
   completions of a device/filename.]
grub> device (hd0) /dev/sda
grub> root (hd0,0)
 Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
grub> setup (hd0)
 Checking if "/boot/grub/stage1" exists... yes
 Checking if "/boot/grub/stage2" exists... yes
 Checking if "/boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5" exists... yes
 Running "embed /boot/grub/e2fs_stage1_5 (hd0)"...  27 sectors are embedded.
succeeded
 Running "install /boot/grub/stage1 (hd0) (hd0)1+27 p (hd0,0)/boot/grub/stage2 /boot/grub/grub.conf"... succeeded
Done.
grub> quit
```

FDISK:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 299.0 GB, 298999349248 bytes, 583983104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9de62695

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1              63     1975994      987966   83  Linux                 // Boot partition for All OS
/dev/sda2   *     1975995    41062139    19543072+  83  Linux                  // rhel7
/dev/sda3        41062140    68420834    13679347+  82  Linux swap / Solaris  //swap
/dev/sda4        68420835   583978814   257778990    5  Extended              
/dev/sda5       146593188   185679269    19543041   83  Linux                // SUSE
/dev/sda6       185679333   224765414    19543041   83  Linux                 // RHEL6 
/dev/sda7       224765478   263851559    19543041   83  Linux                  // OL7
```

grub.conf:

```
title 0 RHEL7 (sda2)

    root (hd0,0)
    kernel /boot/grub2/i386-pc/core.img

title 1 SLES (sda5)
    root (hd0,4)
    chainloader +1

title 2 RHEL6 (sda6)
    root (hd0,5)
    chainloader +1

title 3 OL (sda7)
    root (hd0,6)
    kernel /boot/grub2/i386-pc/core.img
```

Thanks,
SBN

[image]

enter image description here[image]